# Python encoding textfile, open it, replace multiple sections and output without empty lines as text formatted in .csv style

Tags: python, text, encoding, xls

What I have is a file "test.xls" which is basically a old xls (xml formatting) which looks like this in notepad:

```
<table cellspacing="1" rules="all" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Row A</td><td>Row B</td><td>Row C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>New York</td><td>23</td><td>warm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>San Francisco</td><td>40</td><td>hot</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I'm using Python to convert it to a .txt (flatfile) which I can later on import to my MSSQL Database.

What I have so far:

```
import codecs
import os

# read the file with a specific encoding
with codecs.open('test.xls', 'r', encoding = 'ansi') as file_in, codecs.open('test_out.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    lines = file_in.read()
    lines = lines.replace('<tr>', '')

    # save the manipulated data into a new file with new encoding
    file_out.write(lines)
```

This approach results in a .txt like this:

```
Row A;Row B;Row C

New York;23;warm

San Francisco;40;hot
```

I tried to get rid of the empty lines by multiple approaches, the last one was:

```
for lines in file_in:
        if line != '\n':
            file_out.write(lines)
```

But the File either looks the same or is completely empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the empty lines:

list.txt:

```
Row A;Row B;Row C

New York;23;warm

San Francisco;40;hot
```

**Hence**:

```
logFile = "list.txt"
with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]
for line in content:
    print(line)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Row A;Row B;Row C
New York;23;warm
San Francisco;40;hot
```

**EDIT**:

perhaps, to read from the file and then overwrite it, using a list that stores the results which can later be written to the file.

```
logFile = "list.txt"                # your file name
results = []                        # an empty list to store the lines
with open(logFile) as f:            # open the file
    content = f.readlines()         # read the lines

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]   # removing the empty lines
for line in content:
    results.append(line)    # appending each line to the list

print(results)              # printing the list


with open(logFile, "w") as f:    # open the file in write mode
    for elem in results:         # for each line stored in the results list
        f.write(str(elem) + '\n')  # write the line to the file
    print("Thank you, your data was overwritten")  # Tadaa-h!
```

Comment: After i use your last few edit lines i can output it into the console with no empty lines but ä,ö,ü issues. How do i get this result into a file rather than print to console?

Comment: @J.Doe Check the edited answer, I have demonstrated a way to read from the file and then write it back to it.

Comment: i did see that and i'm working on it. just having issues to clearly understand the logic behind the scene. There seems to be some issues with my other replace elements. so after i use readlines() i cannot longer use the replace function so do i have to save the first steps and then load the file again doing the removment of empty lines?

Comment: @J.Doe Sure, Ill do some more comments

Comment: @J.Doe Added comments :)

Comment: Thank you very much. At the end i had to copy your solution and manipulate it to get it work. somewhere along the way of editing my previous solution i lost trak and made i guess some minor mistakes. But now it is working =)